# How automatically to calculate survey scores and ranges?

Tags: cognito-forms

I made a survey with a Likert scale for half and radio buttons for the second half.  Once the survey is complete and submitted, I need the answers (1-5) for each Likert scale question to be added up to a value, then have a result given to the survey taker based on three ranges of scores.  The same needs to be done for the second half with the radio buttons.  Answers need a point value that add up with results compared to set ranges of categories.

Answer (score 2):

I am another developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We quietly released support for calculating scores for rating scales a few months ago.  We elected to keep with our theme of automatic/simple, so the rating values are automatically assigned from 1 to N for each rating, with N/A having a score of zero.  These rating values appear in exports, and you can also access them in calculations.

If you have a rating field called `What is your favorite sport?` and a rating question of `Football`, then you would be able to reference the selected rating using the following in your calculations: `WhatIsYourFavoriteSport.Football_Rating`.  These automatic fields are included in the auto-complete options when writing calculations, so you will not have to guess what to write.

I actually used this on a payment form along with Price field calculations to handle cookie sales, where the type of cookie was the question and the quantities were rating options, so people could quickly select the quantity of each type in a grid to make their purchases.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. We do not currently have a method in place to calculate a survey score. We do think that this feature would be a great addition to our system and have added this to our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/JxoI6Ycc). We do plan to add this feature in the future but do not currently have a date for when it will be ready. Feel free to submit other feature request through our [Request a Feature](https://www.cognitoforms.com/featurerequest) form. We try to keep our members updated to new features we are releasing with a newsletter that is sent out before each release.